# phonegap 2.2 + jQuery + Mapkit plugin

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, ios6, mapkit, phonegap-plugins

I have created a PhoneGap app with jQuery Mobile. What I want to do is get mapkit in a  tag.

The user should not have to click on any buttons to view the map. I want it to appear all the time in div.

Here is the entire example I use
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/iPhone/MapKitPlug/example/index.html

This works great but the user most click show map to show the map.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

                    function onBodyLoad() {
                        document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
                    }

                    /* When this function is called, PhoneGap has been initialized and is ready to roll */
                    function onDeviceReady() {

                    }

                    var pins = [
                    { lat:58.389508,
                            lon:13.843042,
                            title:"place1",
                            subTitle:"placename",
                            pinColor:"purple", 
                            selected:true,
                            index:0
                        },
                                      ]

                     function showMap() {
                        // do your thing!
                        var mapOptions = {
                      height: 360,
                      diameter: 1000,
                      offsetTop: 25,
                      lat: pins[0].lat,
                      lon: pins[0].lon
                    };

                        window.plugins.mapKit.showMap();
                        window.plugins.mapKit.setMapData(mapOptions);
                        window.plugins.mapKit.addMapPins(pins);     
                    }

                </script>      

        </head>

        <body onload="onBodyLoad()">  


                    <button style="top:400px;position:absolute;" onclick="showMap()">Show</button>
```

This works great. But I want to do the same thing but with mapKit plugin for phonegap instead of google maps.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
                    var initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(37.654,-77.980);
                        var myOptions = {
                                        zoom: 12,
                                        center: initialLocation,
                                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                        };
                        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
            });
</script>   
</head> 
<body>
<div data-role="content">   
    <!--images go here -->
    <div class="img_shadow" style="padding:4px;">
                    <div id="map_canvas" style="height:130px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>      
</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the map to load automatically, just call showMap() on page load.

After you defined showMap function:

```
function showMap() {
  // do your thing!
  var mapOptions = {
  height: 360,
  diameter: 1000,
  offsetTop: 25,
  lat: pins[0].lat,
  lon: pins[0].lon
 };

 window.plugins.mapKit.showMap();
 window.plugins.mapKit.setMapData(mapOptions);
 window.plugins.mapKit.addMapPins(pins);   
}
showMap(); // call it
```

Comment: Thank you! But I want to load the map automatically into a div tag. I'm very new to jquery and java. Like the google map exempel.

Comment: That's not possible. This mapkit plugin loads the map as a layer seperate from the web view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the map automatically when page is loaded. You can do like this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   //Your map integration
   window.plugins.mapKit.showMap();

});
```